# Расшаренные папки

Tags: windows

есть 5 компов, у одного из них есть папка exchage, в этой папке есть база access к которой подключаются все остальные компы, если я вырублю этот комп и вместо него поставлю другой и создам папку с похожим именем, расшарю на всех и закину туда базу, то ведь не будет соединения с этой базой? если нет, то как его восстановить?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про локальные сети и общие ресурсы.
Если у вас на всех компах стоит ссылка \ИМЯ_ПК\база_данных, то если новый ПК назовете таким же именем как старый - то все увидят базу. Если по \IP... то надо такой же IP назначить новому ПК. Все зависит от ссылки к подключению базы в приложении.
Так же надо учитывать название расшареной папки и т.п. в общем полностью повторить весь принцип создания общего ресурса на новом ПК.

---

Добавлено от GrayHoax:

> Добавьте в ответ необходимость создания на компьютере учетных записей
>   с теми же именами и паролями, что и на выключаемой машине. Если пароли
>   неизвестны, то нужно перепрописать пароли для подключения на каждом из
>   5 компьютеров. Делается так: Пуск-Выполнить control userpasswords2 ->
>   Дополнительно -> Управление паролями. Нужно удалить установленный
>   пароль и обратиться заново к удаленному ресурсу.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ необходимость создания на компьютере учетных записей с теми же именами и паролями, что и на выключаемой машине. Если пароли неизвестны, то нужно перепрописать пароли для подключения на каждом из 5 компьютеров. Делается так: Пуск-Выполнить `control userpasswords2` -> Дополнительно -> Управление паролями. Нужно удалить установленный пароль и обратиться заново к удаленному ресурсу.

Comment: ip тот же, папка та же, имя компа та же, юзер тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Если папка будет в том же месте,и также расшарена для тех же пользователей и комп в том же домене что и заменяемый, то клиентам, подключающимся к файлу, побоку что поменялся комп. Так что делайте и не бойтесь, все будет работать, если конечно у вас БД именно access

Comment: все сделал именно так, доступ запрещен говорит